# How send a ByteBuffer through Socket?

Tags: java, android, sockets, bytebuffer

I'm working in a remote ScreenRecord in real time based in [this code](http://mattsnider.com/video-recording-with-mediaprojectionmanager/).
With this code of reference i'm able to record screen of my smartphone with success and saving .mp4 file in some folder previous defined.

But to my project, i need that this content be sent to server (similar to Team View for android).

My last attempt to sent this content to server side was like this:

```
OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream (os);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(encodedData);

oos.flush();
bos.flush();
os.flush();
```

Reference => [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320000/efficiently-send-large-int-over-sockets-in-java)

but comes a error of:

> java.io.NotSerializableException
>    in this line > `oos.writeObject(encodedData);`

Then, i want know how solve it or some other way to make this task.

Here is complete code:

```
 /////////////////////////////////////// CLIENTSOCKET ///////////////////////////////////////////

    Socket clientSocket;
    int SERVERPORT = 60;
    String SERVER_IP = "192.168.15.6";

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                new Thread(new CommsThread()).start();

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    class CommsThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for server request");

                while(clientSocket.isConnected()){

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())),true);

                    if (reader.ready()) {
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);

                            if(line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {

                                if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("screenrecord")){

                                    System.out.println(out.toString());

                                    mMediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager)getSystemService(android.content.Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
                                    Intent permissionIntent = mMediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent();
                                    startActivityForResult(permissionIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_PERM);

                                    out.flush();
                                }

                                if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {

                                    stopRecording();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                System.out.println("Shutting down Socket!!");
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////// MEDIAPROJECTION /////////////////////////////////////////

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_PERM = 1234;
    private static final String VIDEO_MIME_TYPE = "video/avc";
    int VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT;

    private boolean mMuxerStarted = false;
    private MediaProjectionManager mMediaProjectionManager;
    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private Surface mInputSurface;
    private MediaMuxer mMuxer;
    private MediaCodec mVideoEncoder;
    private MediaCodec.BufferInfo mVideoBufferInfo;
    private int mTrackIndex = -1;

    private final Handler mDrainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    private Runnable mDrainEncoderRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            drainEncoder();
        }
    };

    public void stopRecording(){

        releaseEncoders();
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        DisplayManager dm = (DisplayManager)getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);
        Display defaultDisplay = dm.getDisplay(Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
        if (defaultDisplay == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No display found.");
        }

        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        int screenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
        VIDEO_WIDTH = screenWidth;
        VIDEO_HEIGHT = screenHeight;

        prepareVideoEncoder();

        mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("Recording Display", screenWidth, screenHeight, screenDensity, 0, mInputSurface, null, null);

        drainEncoder();
    }

    private void prepareVideoEncoder() {
        mVideoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);
        int frameRate = 30;

        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 6000000);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CAPTURE_RATE, frameRate);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER, 1000000 / frameRate);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1);

        try {
            mVideoEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE);
            mVideoEncoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
            mInputSurface = mVideoEncoder.createInputSurface();
            mVideoEncoder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseEncoders();
        }
    }

    private boolean drainEncoder() {
        mDrainHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrainEncoderRunnable);
        while (true) {
            int bufferIndex = mVideoEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mVideoBufferInfo, 0);

            if (bufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                break;
            } else if (bufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {

            } else if (bufferIndex < 0) {

            } else {
                ByteBuffer encodedData = mVideoEncoder.getOutputBuffer(bufferIndex);
                if (encodedData == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("couldn't fetch buffer at index " + bufferIndex);
                }

                if ((mVideoBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
                    mVideoBufferInfo.size = 0;
                }

                if (mVideoBufferInfo.size != 0) {

                        encodedData.position(mVideoBufferInfo.offset);
                        encodedData.limit(mVideoBufferInfo.offset + mVideoBufferInfo.size);

                    try {
                        OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream (os);
                        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
                        oos.writeObject(encodedData);

                        oos.flush();
                        bos.flush();
                        os.flush();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException("couldn't send data to server");
                    }
                } else {

                    }
                       mVideoEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(bufferIndex, false);
                }

                if ((mVideoBufferInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        mDrainHandler.postDelayed(mDrainEncoderRunnable, 10);
        return false;
    }

    private void releaseEncoders() {
        mDrainHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrainEncoderRunnable);
        if (mMuxer != null) {
            if (mMuxerStarted) {
                mMuxer.stop();
            }
            mMuxer.release();
            mMuxer = null;
            mMuxerStarted = false;
        }
        if (mVideoEncoder != null) {
            mVideoEncoder.stop();
            mVideoEncoder.release();
            mVideoEncoder = null;
        }
        if (mInputSurface != null) {
            mInputSurface.release();
            mInputSurface = null;
        }
        if (mMediaProjection != null) {
            mMediaProjection.stop();
            mMediaProjection = null;
        }
        mVideoBufferInfo = null;
        mDrainEncoderRunnable = null;
        mTrackIndex = -1;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_PERM == requestCode) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mMediaProjection = mMediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, intent);
                startRecording();
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When object is not serializable you can't serialize it. Check for `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

Comment: @RomanC, Then what other way that i can send this  **ByteBuffer** via socket?

Comment: Well don't send the ByteBuffer, just send the bytes!

Comment: @JamesKPolk, how exactly? for example if i change `oos.writeObject(encodedData);` to `oos.writeObject(encodedData.array());` cause: *UnsupportedOperationException*.

Comment: It's a read-only ByteBuffer, just create a `byte[]` array and read the contents of the ByteBuffer into it, then write it out.

Comment: @JamesKPolk, ok, this worked. Thank you.